# Unable to add or edit profiles on contribution pages

Tags: wordpress, profile, contribution-page, debugging

I am unable to add, edit or delete profiles from my contribution pages.  I am not sure what is happening.  I decided to not modify reserved profiles and create a custom profiles and trying to change that is no longer possible.  Am I doing something wrong?  On one of my pages there is a text box, though it does nothing, on the other, there is nothing.

Also occurs when I try and make a new contribution page.  Using Wordpress 4.7.5, CiviCRM 4.7.16 - Occurs in Chrome, Firefox, even in incognito mode.

[image: Screenshot of "Include Profile" field on the contribution page setup]

[image: "DB Error: constraint violation" displays when I type anything in that text box]

Comment: What WordPress theme are you using?

Comment: Hi @KilakwaBT I am using 2017 - The Wordpress released theme.

Comment: What plugins do you have installed?

Comment: @choster backtrace updated.

Comment: @KilakwaBT I think I figured out the problem.  I went through and deactivated each plugin separately (don't know why I didn't think to do that before) and found that Jetpack was causing the problem which is concerning because we use Jetpack to protect our site.  When jetpack is deactivated, the profile fields appear, when jetpack is activated, it appears like the images above.

Comment: I have seen Jetpack cause this but not always. Visual Composer can be another culprit. It can sometimes be the combination of the theme & plugin. Sorry I can't give you definitive answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out that Jetpack conflicts with CiviCRM - Fix for now is to disable Jetpack when using CiviCRM Profiles on contribution pages and then reactivate when done. Also note:  Jetpack also impacts the ability to edit a calendar date in CiviEvents.

**Update:**
In speaking with Jetpack, the Jetpack Notifications module relies on Backbone.js and is in conflict with CiviCRM.  There is already a ticket discussing conflict with backbone.js and a multitude of wordpress plugins with CiviCRM.  Instead of deactivating Jetpack everytime you need to access a profile or edit a date, simply disable the Notifications Module at http://yoursite.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=jetpack_modules

They are working on making the feature easier to access and enable when it’s disabled. https://github.com/Automattic/jetpack/issues/6788

Now I am able to use Jetpack sans the Notifications module which I don't care about and CiviCRM without any issues.